# Redshift - Passing values from a csv in a where clause

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-redshift, where-clause

I have a csv file that list of sale_ids (about 10K entries). I am wondering if there is a way to pass these values from the file as part of the where clause in a SQL statement.

Given below is the SQL:

```
select s.sale_id,s.sale_date,prod.prod_name 
from sales s, product prod
where s.prod_id = prod.id
and s.sale_id in (these are the IDs in the csv file)
```

The csv has just one column with sale_id

I am trying to do this on a Redshift DB. Thanks.

Comment: you have to copy this file as a table to Redshift and then reference it in a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually or programmatically insert all the values into the SQL query, but there is no in-built capability within Amazon Redshift to insert the contents of a CSV file into a query.

As suggested by @AlexYes, you could use the `COPY` command to load that CSV file into a new table, then reference that table within your query:

```
and s.sale_id in (SELECT thing FROM new_table)
```